# new to programming, need a nudge with a decimal point

Tags: c#, int, double, decimal

Im new to programming so bear with me, I have a simple enough problem that I want to get through and I will hopefully figure it out from there.  I want to multiply a number by .23, so i can get a percentage.  when i debug it doesnt work, i know its not a big problem but iv been searching around and i cant figure it out, any help?

```
 float percengage = .23f;

//Cost of Paint
        percengage = .23f;
        totalCostOfPaint = pricePaintPerGallon * percengage;

 Console.WriteLine("Cost of paint:" + totalCostOfPaint);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ? what is the type of `totalCostOfPaint` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if the notation `.23f` is valid (maybe it should be `0.23f`).

Comment: @GiulioFranco `.23f` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Anyway, you should include the declaration of all the variables you're using. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: I've declared all the variables, is there any way I can declare the variables as a string and float at the same time?

Comment: @jeddie No - you have to make a separate string variable, and *convert* the floating point number into a string as needed.  There are many ways to represent a number as text.

Answer (score 4):

Your `totalCostOfPaint` variable would need to be declared as a `float`, `double`, or `decimal` for this to work properly, as written.

It's very common, when dealing with monetary values, to use `decimal` for all computations, as it provides more precision.

Note that you may want to change the formatting, as well (to print as currency):

```
  // Note that pricePaintPerGallon needs to be declared properly, as well...

  decimal percengage = 0.23M;
  decimal totalCostOfPaint = pricePaintPerGallon * percengage;
  Console.WriteLine("Cost of paint: {0:C}", totalCostOfPaint);
```

Comment: +1 to offset the person who downvoted (without a supporting comment) and also, because this is the correct answer.

Comment: Anytime.  And 'hello' to a fellow Washingtonian!

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I see is that you aren't declaring the `totalCostOfPaint` and `pricePaintPerGallon` variables. Since it's not working, I can only assume you haven't  declared those somewhere else in your code. If you do, it works fine:

```
float percengage = .23f;
float pricePaintPerGallon = .99f;    
float totalCostOfPaint = pricePaintPerGallon * percengage;

Console.WriteLine("Cost of paint:" + totalCostOfPaint);
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/KNIUNQ58221

Just so you know, variables in C# have to be declared (meaning set up and described) before you use them. The compiler needs to know that `percengage`, `pricePaintPerGallon`, and `totalCostOfPaint` are local variables, and that they will be of type `float`. You're already doing this for `percengage` by putting the word `float` in front of it on the first line.